# How to make user profile page display extra fields in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

I have added some extra fields to users under admin/people/ - when I click edit beside the user, I can see the extra fields I have added.

However, if I go to /user/ those fields are not displayed.

How do I display user profile fields when their profile is viewed at /user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely added the fields through this admin page:
admin/config/people/accounts/fields

To control which fields are actually displayed on the view page, go here:
admin/config/people/accounts/display

Also if you have the Field Permissions module enabled, make sure all necessary roles have the permission to view the fields you've added.

Comment: tommi, thanks for the quick answer. i made everything "inline", but still nothing is showing..

Comment: Seems you're editing the "label" setting. That only controls whether the name of the field is displayed. You need to drag your fields above the "hidden" mark: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3093436/userfields.png

Comment: So in the image I posted only the "about" field is visible, because it's above the "hidden" mark. You can make a field (like "real name" in my pic) visible by either dragging with arrows on the left hand side or by changing the format dropdown to something other than "hidden".

Comment: tommi, they are not under the hidden mark. drupal slaps me in the face yet again..

Comment: Have you edited the template for the user page?

Comment: no I have not touched that template

Comment: Wow, that's kind of screwed up.

What type of fields are they?

Comment: so under admin/configuration/account settings/manage fields they are text fields, and checkboxes/radio buttons

Comment: Can you post pictures of your "manage fields" and "manage display" forms, a user edit form and the corresponding user view?

Comment: sorry tommi i found my mistake...i was editing the wrong user all this time so when i clicked "root" nothing was showing for me...sorry to have wasted your time and curiosity

Comment: Hahaha. Classic. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

A very belated reply that might help someone else.

I had a similar problem where I was going to populate the fields from another source and so the user wasn't to be allowed to edit them. I could see the fields as an administrator but not as the user.

The cause in this case was that the fields would only display if they had data in them. Adding data as an administrator made them visible (but read-only).